Mysterious IP address using up quota in GCP
I only have three external IP addresses:

Two of these are from my K8s cluster and the first one is from a compute engine VM.
However, I can't create the third node in my cluster because my quota of four external IPs is somehow exhausted.

And no, I don't have a load balancer.


As per the official documentation about External IP addresses

If the same External IP address is assigned to more than one forwarding rule, Google Cloud counts and adds each usage of the address towards the IN_USE_ADDRESSES quota rather than a unique count of IP address objects that are used. This might be a reason for the quota limit exhaustion for External IP addresses.

Also you can raise a quota increase request for this issue by contacting your cloud provider(GCP) and another alternative is to use the Network Address Translation.

your last link isn't a link - why does this answer stink of chatGPT?

I have updated the answer and provided the correct link. Did you have time to check my answer? I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.
